# If $A$ commutes with $B$ and $B$ commutes with $C$, then $A$ commutes with $C$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

> Let $A,B,C \in \ M(3,\mathbb{R})$ be such that $A$ commutes with $B $and $B$ commutes with $C$. $B$ is not scalar matrix. Then, $A$ commutes with $C$.

Is this true or false? I think it is not true, but cannot think of a counterexample. Any suggestions?

Comment: What if $B$ is the zero matrix?

Comment: $B$ is not scalar matrix

Answer (score 5):

Take $B$ such as $b_{11}=1$, $b_{ij}=0$ for $(i,j)\neq (1,1)$. This is no scalar matrix, but it is easy to see that it commutes with everything, in particular with two non-commutable matrices.

Comment: It does not commute with everything. But with enough things for this purpose.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft You are right, but almost, and in particular with non-commuting matrices.

Comment: @Martigan Not quite to your last comment, unless you write "with **some couple** of non-commuting matrices", which of course should be produced on demand...

Comment: @DonAntonio It was indeed the way I intended my tatement to be read. "Some" is a key implied word. And of course I let the OP search by himself, for in that case, it is fairly easy to find.